# Gdal/QGIS resampling asc file

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem, resampling

I have a DEM (.asc) file with a resolution of 1000 meters per pixel. Therefore the file has a lot of columns and rows.
I would like to chance the resolution per pixel from 1000 to 3000 meters per pixel. So i would like to resample it.

which gdal command do i use for this?
i know it's gdalwarp but how is the exact command line with the extra options?

if you know how to do it in QGIS I'm also happy with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task could feel trivial by reading the gdalwarp documentation http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html and GDAL AAIGrid -- Arc/Info ASCII Grid driver documentation http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html. The target pixel size is three times bigger than the native resolution 0.008333333333 degrees/pixel (not 1000 m/pixel, see the comments).

```
gdalwarp -of AAIGrid -tr 0.024999 0.024999 input.asc output.asc
```

However, it is a bit more difficult than that.

- gdalwarp does not support AAIGrid format as direct output format
- The default resampling method of gdalwarp is nearest neighbor which does not suit well for DEM

Therefore the conversion must be done in two steps and with a better resampling method.

First step is to create an interim output as GDAL Virtual raster (.VRT) with "average" resampling

```
gdalwarp -of VRT -r average -tr 0.024999 0.024999 input.asc interim.vrt
```

Second step is to convert the interim DEM into new ASCII Grid file with gdal_translate

```
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid interim.vrt output.asc
```

**Note**:

The formats which are supported for output can be listed with gdalwarp --formats command. Formats which support direct output are marked with "+" character. However, all of them will not really work (NTv2 Datum Grid Shift file for example).

On Windows

```
gdalwarp --formats|find "+"
  FITS -raster- (rw+): Flexible Image Transport System
  HDF4Image -raster- (rw+): HDF4 Dataset
  netCDF -raster- (rw+s): Network Common Data Format
  VRT -raster- (rw+v): Virtual Raster
  GTiff -raster- (rw+vs): GeoTIFF
  NITF -raster- (rw+vs): National Imagery Transmission Format
  HFA -raster- (rw+v): Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
  ELAS -raster- (rw+v): ELAS
  MEM -raster- (rw+): In Memory Raster
  BMP -raster- (rw+v): MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
  PCIDSK -raster,vector- (rw+v): PCIDSK Database File
  ILWIS -raster- (rw+v): ILWIS Raster Map
  SGI -raster- (rw+): SGI Image File Format 1.0
  Leveller -raster- (rw+): Leveller heightfield
  Terragen -raster- (rw+): Terragen heightfield
  ISIS2 -raster- (rw+v): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 2)
  ERS -raster- (rw+v): ERMapper .ers Labelled
  RMF -raster- (rw+v): Raster Matrix Format
  RST -raster- (rw+v): Idrisi Raster A.1
  INGR -raster- (rw+v): Intergraph Raster
  GSBG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)
  GS7BG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software 7 Binary Grid (.grd)
  PNM -raster- (rw+v): Portable Pixmap Format (netpbm)
  ENVI -raster- (rw+v): ENVI .hdr Labelled
  EHdr -raster- (rw+v): ESRI .hdr Labelled
  PAux -raster- (rw+): PCI .aux Labelled
  MFF -raster- (rw+): Vexcel MFF Raster
  MFF2 -raster- (rw+): Vexcel MFF2 (HKV) Raster
  BT -raster- (rw+v): VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
  LAN -raster- (rw+v): Erdas .LAN/.GIS
  IDA -raster- (rw+v): Image Data and Analysis
  GTX -raster- (rw+v): NOAA Vertical Datum .GTX
  NTv2 -raster- (rw+vs): NTv2 Datum Grid Shift
  CTable2 -raster- (rw+v): CTable2 Datum Grid Shift
  KRO -raster- (rw+v): KOLOR Raw
  ADRG -raster- (rw+vs): ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
  SAGA -raster- (rw+v): SAGA GIS Binary Grid (.sdat)
  PDF -raster,vector- (rw+vs): Geospatial PDF
```

Comment: Be sure to use `-r average`, otherwise the downsampling will pick the middle pixel and ignore the other 8.

Comment: That's right and sooner or later you just must read the documentation, try to understand it and make your own experiments with demo data instead of trusting on the inaccurate answers we give to you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

but it appears "Output driver "AAIGrid" not recognised or does not support direct output file creation." Any solution?

Comment: It looks like it is compiled by default http://gdal.org/formats_list.html so then it is the other alternative, not supported as direct output. Try then with -of GTiff and convert geotiff into asc later with gdal_translate. I will edit my answer it that works.

Comment: You can find a list of `direct output` formats here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101387/gdalwarp-wont-export-aaigrid

Comment: Why not use a .vrt for temporary output? Saves a lot of disk space...

Comment: so i have to create a .vrt and then translate it to .asc?

therefore it should look like that, no?

gdalwarp -of vrt -tr 3000 3000 -r average input.asc output.vrt

right? with this command it appears "Copying color table from input.asc to new file. Creating output file that is 0* + 0L. Error 1: Attempt to create 0*0 dataset is illegal, sizes must be larger than zero"

Comment: What do you get if you run galinfo on the input file? Maybe you have to add extent and SRS as well.

Comment: Commands as they are now in my answer are tested with real data. Computed output size of 0 by 0 pixels make me think if the source resolution is really 1000 meters.

Comment: then i get 8752 lines with 254, 254, 253, 255. It's a DEM of nearly whole Southamerica.

the grid: 
ncols        10800
nrows        6000
xllcorner    -90.000000000000
yllcorner    -49.999999998000
cellsize     0.008333333333
NODATA_value -500

Comment: You get a four-band RGBA file, maybe you should force one-band float or integer with -ot. Your extent data looks like degrees, and cellsize is not 1000 meters, but 0.00833 degrees.

Comment: yes that was the problem. When i multiply the degrees with 3, its works! Thank you.