# Reproject Output as ASCII

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal

I want re-project my Esri Arcinfo ASCII (.asc) raster file to Albers Equal Area Projection Which is currently in WGS84 and output it as .asc file. But gdalwarp cannot output as .asc file but gdaltranslate can. Is there anyway that i can use gdalwarp output as gdaltranslate input.

Comment: `gdalwarp` then `gdal_translate`. If using GDAL 2x, you can do it directly `gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:26711 -t_srs EPSG:4326 input.asc /vsistdout/ | gdal_translate -of AAIGrid /vsistdin/ output.asc`. If using GDAL 1x you need to gdalwarp to VRT then gdal_translate `gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:26711 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of VRT input.asc output.vrt` `gdal_translate -of AAIGrid output.vrt output.asc`

Comment: @BradHards its true, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101387/gdalwarp-wont-export-aaigrid/101423#101423

Comment: @Luke closed as too broad would not help future visitors, while marking as a duplicate may help them.

Comment: can I delete it? @ luke

Comment: No, I have flagged it for moderator attention.